# javascript error by a jsf "page forward"

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

I’m in the starting phase of a new jsf+primefaces project. I have to include some company-wide css and javascript files into our jsf template. The company-wide css/js are provided by a cms and we cannot change them.

I managed this, in this way:

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>       
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"     
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"     
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"     
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"     
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">     
 <h:head>     
 <f:facet name="middle">     
   <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="own.css" />     
   <h:outputScript library="js" name="own.js" />     
  </f:facet>     
  <f:facet name="last">     
   <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="company-wide.css" />     
 </f:facet>     
 </h:head>     
 <h:body>     

 //some code     

  <h:outputScript library="js/wcms" name="company-wide.js" />     
 </h:body>     
 </html>
```

The company-wide.js has also jquery in it (of course in a different version).

When the page is fully loaded, everything works fine (in IE 8 / 9, chrome and firefox). Then I jump to another page by “Page forward” (no redirect), the IE throws a javascript exception “Error Code: 80020101“. The cource of the error is (I assume), a jquery version missmatch.

When I do a redirect within the page jump, it works fine.

My explanation is, that the redirect loads the full page (of course), therefore it works as the page is loaded the first time.

But what happen by a “page forward”, why do I have than a js conflict?

Comment: It seems like your javascript file is not going to be included when you are using forward for redirection.